# Sending parameters with web3 .send is throwing MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, ganache

I'm trying to call a function with parameters with web3 v1.7.0 `.send()` method which works fine without any parameters but fails when including them.

A simplified version:

```java
contract Master{
constructor() {}
event AgreementCalled(address[] indexed initialParticipants);
function createAgreement(address[] memory initialParticipants) external {
    emit AgreementCalled (initialParticipants);
    }
}
```

called from Javascript with web3

```js
let contractTransaction =  await MasterContract.methods.createAgreement(["0x26..7b", "0xeA8..A3e" ])
          .send({from:currentAccount});
```

I get the following console error

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert","code":-32000,"data":{"0x680b1ed2c6c24f5150a4fa5d1c764d134d25ab122e14891a2348087e6e7eb51e":{"error":"revert","program_counter":81,"return":"0x"},
```

Interestingly enough, Ganache UI shows the transaction, including the array
[image: Ganache displays values]

- If I remove the parameter (an array of addresses) it works fine, like so: `MasterContract.methods.createAgreement().send({from:currentAccount});`
- If I change the array with a simple string both in the contract and javascript, I get the same error.
- Adding lots of gas, like `.send({from:this.eth.currentAccount, gas: 10000000})` doesn't solve it
- Using Web3 1.7.0, solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0, Ganache
- From Remix it works just fine

Any idea on what can be going on?

Comment: Can you share the ABI that you're passing to the web3 instance? Just the `createAgreement` part is sufficient. It might have an outdated value from earlier development stage, not corresponding with the actual deployed contract... Also, can you check that the addresses are valid? Correct length ("0x" plus 40 characters), only hex characters?

Comment: Hi Petr. Thanks for replying. The ABI looks alright to me. Yes, I shortened the addresses, but they are okay : `["0xB031c45eC644936126da68104470380c88145633", "0xc1243460b4c1648Bdf65c8fDf15d7f031777EC8D"]`. The ABI: `
 {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "createAgreement",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },`